# Chart(Fsharp.Charting) not respond

Tags: f#, f#-charting

Having this code:

```
let errorChanged = new Event<(int * float)>()

let learn error data w w_ iter =
    let rec learning error data w w_ i icount =
        //recursive(loop) fire event
        errorChanged.Trigger(i, e) //trigger event for chart update
        if (/**/) then
            learning /*params*/
        else
            /*do else*/

    let plot = LiveChart.PointIncremental(errorChanged.Publish |> Event.every 5)
    plot.ShowChart()
    learning error data w w_ 0 iter
```

when i run it, i see Point Chart window, which is not respond (and not updating).
According to [code samples](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Charting/LiveChartSamples.html) this should works well, but...
How can i fix this?

**UPD**:

if i do:

```
let rec learning error data w w_ i icount = async {
            let e = Seq.fold (fun s x ->
                                         s + errorPart w w_ x x) 0.0 data
            errorChanged.Trigger(i, e)
            if (e > error && i <= iter) then
                printfn "[iter] = %d of %d. [e] = %f" i icount e
                let (w, w_) = Seq.fold (fun (w, w_) x -> 
                                                learnPart w w_ x x) (w, w_) data
                return! learning error data (normalize w) (normalize w_) (i + 1) icount
            else
                let resultData = Seq.map (fun x -> calculatePart w w_ x) data
                let y = resultData
                        |> Seq.map (fun (y, _) -> y) 
                        |> Seq.concat
                let x_ = resultData
                        |> Seq.map (fun (_, x_) -> x_) 
                        |> Seq.concat
                return (w, w_, e, y, x_) }

        let plot = LiveChart.PointIncremental(errorChanged.Publish |> Event.every 5)
        plot.ShowChart()
        async { return! learning error data w w_ 0 iter}
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

i get exception: *Cross-thread operation not valid*.
Seems like i need something like `Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code snippet is that it creates the chart, but then it runs the `learning` function on the current thread and so it blocks the main thread (which never gets a chance to update the chart).

You can wrap the `learning` function in `async { .. }` block and run it using `Async.Start`. Then it will run in the background and the chart will be able to update.

You did not post complete code, so I was not able to test, but I think the following should work:

```
let rec learning error data w w_ i icount = async { // Async block here!
    (* omitted *)
    errorChanged.Trigger(i, e) //trigger event for chart update
    if (e > error && i <= iter) then
        (* omitted *) 
        // Here, we now need to run the recursive call using 'return!' of async
        return! learning error data (normalize w) (normalize w_) (i + 1) icount
    else
        (* omitted *)
        return (w, w_, e, y, x_) }

let plot = LiveChart.PointIncremental(errorChanged.Publish |> Event.every 5)
plot.ShowChart()

// Create workflow that will run 'learning' and then print the result
// (this needs to return unit, so that we can use 'Async.Start')
async { let! res = learning error data w w_ 0 iter 
        printfn "Finished: %A" res } 
|> Async.Start
```

Comment: I need to return result from `learn` function, but this code returns `unit`. see **UPD**.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably a lack of an [WinForms event loop](https://twitter.com/dsyme/status/489079506318000128).

Try this simple code to see if it hangs first, then apply it to your plot

```
use form = new Form(Width=400, Height=300, Visible=true, Text="Hello charting")
Chart.Line([for x in 0 ..10 -> x, x+x]).ShowChart()
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form)
```